# why cant I generate with gii in Yii2?

Tags: php, web, yii2, gii

I made the view table with function "join" in sql. but when I try to generate the view table with gii, it was said that "Table associated with Rangkuman must have primary key", and I have made primary key with table that associated with Rangkuman. What should I do? Thank you so much

Here is my picture
[image]

Comment: Please show us the content of your `Rangkuman` model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I create CRUD with GII in Yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504811/why-cant-i-create-crud-with-gii-in-yii2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your model class after giving primary key.